# Using EF Core to delete item from ToDo list

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, todoist

I was asked to update the API and implement the `RemoveToDoItem` from the following code:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}", Name = "DeleteTodoItem")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveTodoItem(int id)
{
    // TODO
    // Use EF Core to remove the item based on id

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This is the error code I get when I attempt to run the program

> HttpRequestException: you must first implement the API endpoint.
> Candidate.Web.Services.CandidateApi.RemoveTodoItem(int id) in CandidateApi.cs

```
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("You must first implement the API endpoint.");
        }

        throw new HttpRequestException("You must first implement the API endpoint.");
```

Not entirely sure how to go about this. I've tried to use the `DeleteTodoItem` variable but no luck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some guidelines to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1. Inject your [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext) into the controller by adding it to the constructor parameters.
2. Use the [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.remove) method on the `DbSet<T>` property of your `DbContext` to mark the entity for deletion.
3. Call [`SaveChangesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync) to persist the changes to the database.

```
[HttpDelete("{id}", Name = "DeleteTodoItem")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveTodoItem(int id)
{
    var todoItem = await _dbContext.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

    if (todoItem == null)
        return NotFound();

    _dbContext.TodoItems.Remove(todoItem);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helpful. Another question. How would I inject DbContext into the controller by adding it to the constructor parameters?

Would I need to create a new class titled under the Models folder? So far I have something like this:

    public class AppDbContext :DbContext
    {
    }
}

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection

Comment: I've created a models folder for _dbContext. That looks like this

    {
        public static object Todos { get; set; }
        public static object Async { get; set; }

        public static object TodoItems { get; set; }
  }

Now the only error code that shows up is for FindAsync ('object does not contain definition and no accessible extension method) and .SaveChanges Async (does not contain definition). Feels like I'm close?